# How to debug C++ project using Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to use Qt Creator on macOS to debug a C++ project but it seems to be stuck at something. Check the screenshot below.

[image]

I would like to see the contents of charset array.

Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: LLDB integration of QtCreator seems to be buggy.

Comment: seems to be a bug in QTCreator itself, does xcode debugs this properly?

Comment: xcode works fine

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same in the past when trying to debug on Android devices.

If you are not not using the latest version of QtCreator, you should do so.

If the problem persists, you should report a Qt bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/. Then they will hopefully fix it for the next release.

Answer (score 0):

I use CDB to debug the same code, and it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the yellow warning triangles in your pic, it appears that the code model is warning you that you're using uninitialized data. (I'm actually surprised your compiler let you do this.) I'm wondering whether the array you're trying to read has been optimized out, and the debugger is getting confused about what to display.

I'd suggest initializing that array, and seeing whether the debugger can then show you the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I can see three potential problems with your code:

Bug #1: you don't initialise `charset` to zero (using `memset`), so it will contain unpredictable values.

Bug #2: You never `delete` the `charset` array, so your available memory will get smaller and smaller as the program runs. (You can fix these two bugs by declaring `bool charset[256];`)

Potential bug #3: `val` is a `char`. So if `char` is signed by default on your system, then `val` can be negative, and not suitable for use as an array index.

But I don't know why you can't examine the contents of `charset`.