# Can I have source code ouside project folder in xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode

I just created my first xcode C++ project. Directory structure looks like the following:

```
myproject
+-xproject
  +-xproject
  | +-main.cpp
  +-xproject.xcodeproj
```

Let me describe it (not sure if its necessary). The base folder is `myproject`, everything inside it was created by xcode.

Instead, I would like have `main.cpp` outside, like the following:

```
myproject
+-main.cpp
+-xproject
  +-xproject.xcodeproj
```

Is that possible? How can I get things this way?

Why I want that? Because different IDEs offer different benefits (and debugging in qtcreator might be less straightforward than in xcode, [How to debug C++ project using Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64074287/how-to-debug-c-project-using-qt-creator))

Actually `xproject.xcodeproj` is a folder which contains:

```
xproject/xproject.xcodeproj
├── project.pbxproj
├── project.xcworkspace
│   ├── contents.xcworkspacedata
│   ├── xcshareddata
│   │   └── IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist
│   └── xcuserdata
│       └── user.xcuserdatad
│           └── UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
└── xcuserdata
    └── user.xcuserdatad
        └── xcschemes
            └── xcschememanagement.plist
```

What I tried (looks like Eljay approach): Open project on xcode, remove `xproject/main.cpp` and then add `myproject/main.cpp`. Hit play button and it says build succedded. But also says:

```
Could not launch "xproject"
LLDB provided no error string.
```

When I click details I get:

```
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: LLDB provided no error string.
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 855031;
    RawLLDBErrorMessage = "LLDB provided no error string.";
}
```

Comment: why do you want that? IDEs help you a lot when building a project. You can always ignore IDEs conventions and build the project on your own, ie you can put your sources wherever you like

Comment: My experience with IDEs in general (including Xcode) is *don't fight the tool*.  But if you want to, create a project, delete the placeholder source files, then try to add your files from their locations and see what happens.  If it works, you're golden.  If it doesn't, *c'est la vie*.  That being said, my project uses tools to generate the Xcode project in a different location than from the source code, so I can confirm that it is **possible**.

Comment: idclev 463035818, let's say I want to make it easy to edit `main.cpp` using two different IDEs, xcode and qtcreator. Is this an acceptable answer for your question?

Comment: its not up to me to decide if that is an acceptable reason. I just think your question needs a bit of context.

Comment: Eljay would you give me an advise on how to generate the xcode project?

Comment: I am seeing a similar error. When I do, the final build product is coloured red. In my case, I think the build was failing quietly because my source was in blue sub folders, that arrived when I added files to the project, but selected folders. When I added all the files in a flat structure, the build succeeded and to problem went away. Maybe your problem is something else entirely, but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

```
ln -s xproject/main.cpp main.cpp
```

Although I don't like this solution because the original file have to be inside xcode project.

I tried the oposite, but then xcode refuses to work.